# JPEG file quantization table definition

Tags: compression, jpeg, quantization

When I use Photoshop Save As function, and pick jpeg file format I get following window:

[image]

As you can see, I select *Baseline ("Standard")* format, and maximum picture quality. When I open this picture in Hex editor, I see several FF DB markers (which is start of Quantization table/s). No problem yet, but lets look next picture:
[image]

As you can see form picture above, at address row `BDA` starts FFDB marker. First two bytes are 00 84 which means that this marker holds 132 bytes of data. Doing some math, we can conclude that two Quantization tables are defined by this marker. Values of first table are: 0C 08 08 08 09 etc...

In the same file, there is another FFDB marker, starting from 2885 address row, as you can see in picture:

[image]

Again, value of first two bytes are 00 84 which means 132 bytes of data. But this time, first Quantization table values are: 01 01 01 etc...

***How to know which of FF DB markers should I use, and why there is several FFDB markers in file?***

Comment: Mr. M - for questions like these, you can just email me directly :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without seeing the entire file, it's hard to say with certainty, but it looks like your first quantization table is for an embedded thumbnail which is compressed with a lower quality. The second quantization table is for the main image and has values of 01,01,01,... because you chose the highest quality and therefore the coefficient values are quantized the least possible amount.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Now I know there can be multiple QT-s in a single JPEG file. But - 1 question: can I rely on the byte sequence `0xFFDB` (or, rather: `0xFFDB0043` for a single QT and `0xFFDB0048` for two QT-s) to always be a followed by some QT, or do we need a better way of finding the QTs?

Comment: @TomaszGandor JPEG data is arranged so that any byte sequence beginning with 0xFF (and not followed by 0x00) is a marker, so yes, 0xFFDB is always going to be a quantization table. The next 2 bytes are the big-endian length. Since a QT must include 64 values, 0x43 is for 1 table and 0x84 would be for 2.

Comment: Be aware, that the 'real' quantization table does not start directly after the length field but 1 byte later. The second table also has the Pq&Tq 1 byte prepended. See https://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/itu-t81.pdf (B.2.4.1).