# Reading quantization tables of jpeg files on Android

Tags: java, image, kotlin, jpeg

[A previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17643518/50065) provides code for reading the quantization tables of jpeg files in Java. However it uses `javax.imageio.ImageIO` which, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16813721/50065), isn't available on the Android platform.

How can I read read the quantization tables of jpeg files on Android in Kotlin or the Java subset available on Android?

**edit**

I have found the [korlibs/korim](https://github.com/korlibs/korim) Kotlin library which seems to [read the quantization tables](https://github.com/korlibs/korim/blob/master/old/korim-jpeg/src/commonMain/kotlin/com/soywiz/korim/format/jpg/JPEGDecoder.kt). But I'm still a beginner with Kotlin so I haven't yet figured out how I go from a string with the path to the JPEG file to printing out the quantization table.

Answer (score 2):

I am, unfortunately, not aware of such an API for Android.

However, parsing the JPEG quantization tables aren't that hard... You could probably have a look at my [JPEGSegmentUtil](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/master/imageio/imageio-metadata/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/metadata/jpeg/JPEGSegmentUtil.java) and [QuantizationTable](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/master/imageio/imageio-jpeg/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/plugins/jpeg/QuantizationTable.java) (originally by Helmut Dersch) classes and adapt them to Android. The mentioned code is available under BSD license.

You would need to replace the `javax.imageio.ImageInputStream` with a different type, preferably something that implements `java.io.DataInput` and has proper seek/skip, replace `javax.imageio.IIOException` with normal `IOException`, and perhaps a few more tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to read quantization tables then the simplest solution would be to implement parsing yourself. Basic sample (in C#; but Java/Kotlin implementation is pretty similar): https://stackoverflow.com/a/46162800/136138

This conversation might also be useful: [JPEG file quantization table definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275754/jpeg-file-quantization-table-definition)

---

If you need to do more JPEG-related operations then look at [JpegKit](https://github.com/CameraKit/jpegkit-android) that wraps the native [libjpeg-turbo library](https://libjpeg-turbo.org/).